# Let $G$ be an abelian group can we always construct a quasi projective variety $X$ such that Cl$(X)=G$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-groups

Recall that for a quasi projective variety $X$ one can define the [Divisor Class Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)) denoted by Cl$(X)$

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Can we always construct a quasi projective variety $X$ such that Cl$(X)=G$ ?

By a exercise I know that if $X$ is variety then  Cl$(X \times \mathbb P^n)=$Cl$(X) \times \mathbb Z$,So it is clear that  we can always construct $X$ such that  Cl$(X)= \frac {\mathbb Z}{d \mathbb Z} \times \mathbb Z^r$ for some given $d$ and $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes; Claborn showed every abelian group is a class group of a Dedekind domain, and

> C. R. Leedham-Green, "The class group of Dedekind domains," *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* 163 (1972), 493–500. doi:[10.2307/1995734](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1995734)

gives a geometric construction using affine curves, if I remember correctly.